# Create a block dynamically in controller and send its html in response to ajax request

Tags: magento2

I had done this a lot of times but i got stuck on this. 
In my block class i have set the template file and in my controller i'm trying to get the html but every time it is returning an empty string.

Here are the code files

Products.php (Block class)

```
<?php
namespace 
Vendor\Module\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option;

class Products extends 
\Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option
{
/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $_template = 
'catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/products.phtml';

protected $products;

public function setProducts($products)
{
    $this->products= $products;
    return $this;
}

public function getProducts()
{
    return $this->products;
}
}
```

In Controller, wrote this code to get html,

```
$html = $this->_view->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option\Products')
        ->setProducts($productList)
        ->toHtml();
```

I have tried it with resultPageFactory in place of _view object.

I have exactly the same implementation working fine in other template file.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory` or `\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory`

see below:

```
<?php
namespace Mbs\QuickView\Controller\Product;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory
     */
    private $viewJsonFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $productRepository;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    private $registry;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    private $pageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $viewJsonFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->viewJsonFactory = $viewJsonFactory;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Execute action based on request and return result
     *
     * Note: Request will be added as operation argument in future
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|ResponseInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

        try {
            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product */
            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId, false, $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
            $this->registry->register('current_product', $product);
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            // log exception
        }

       

        $result = [
            'sku' => $product->getSku()
        ];
        $jsonResult = $this->viewJsonFactory->create();
        $jsonResult->setData($result);

        return $jsonResult;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my problem is that template(phtml file) is not rendered in the block.